# Add Column to Table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I looked around for an answer to this. How to add a column using SQL in an Oracle Database.

I keep finding the same answer, but my Oracle SQL Developer tool keeps telling me that the syntax is wrong even though I write it exactly as they do.

What am I missing exactly? (Before you ask, yes I do use ALTER TABLE before this)

The syntax is supposed to be:

```
ADD Column_Name constraint Data_Type;
```

Issue is, I have no constraints for this column so I've seen examples not use it. I tried that as well and I get the same error. The value can be null and have no constraints, yet I am not allowed to do this:

```
ADD SERIES_YEAR NUMBER(2,10);
```

Any suggestions? It's probably something incredibly simple.

EDIT: Here is the error it gives me:

[image: Error]

Comment: care to post the exact error you're getting?

Comment: @raviolicode Added it now :)

Comment: Maybe add the actual statement you are executing as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing parentheses. Try the following:

```
ALTER TABLE 
    Foo
ADD
(
    SERIES_YEAR NUMBER(2,10) NOT NULL,
);
```

You have to write the data type before the constraint, not the opposite, like:

```
ADD
(
    column1_name column1_datatype column1_constraint,  
    column2_name column2_datatype column2_constraint
);
```

Comment: `You are missing parentheses` - not for a single `ADD` as in OP's question (hmm, according to http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_3001.htm#i2103924 you are right, but for me it worked without the parantheses)

Comment: True, I missed that ;)

Comment: Seems that it is not *that* straight forward - it might even depend on the client/driver which is used: http://bytes.com/topic/oracle/answers/65501-alter-table-requires-extra-parentheses-oracle

Comment: Apparently the parenthesis was all that's missing..well that's dumb ._. Thanks though! Fixed it.